# How to put maven settings.xml with password in source control

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

I'm building a docker image for a jenkins slave. That jenkins slave will have to push and pull artifacts to/from an artifacts repository.

This is for Java and maven projects. So I need to have in my docker container a settings.xml so that I can authenticate in several private repositories.

My idea would be to copy a settings.xml in the Dockerfile, but because it has sensitive information (username, password), I'm concerned about security. Can I encrypt this content in the source control? And more important, can I avoid people from just downloading this file and being able to use the encrypted credentials? Ideally I should have a mechanism to make sure the encrypted file only works in the context of the docker container.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case very helpful was https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Comment: Create a master password and use it to encrypt passwords in settings.xml. Upload the encrypted file to source control. settings-security.xml should exist in the docker image to be able to decrypt the passwords. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Comment: @ben5556 the problem for me exactly that. I can add the encrypted file to source control, but since I'm also adding the settings-security.xml to decrypt in the dockerfile, everyone will be able to use it and decrypt the file. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand credentials for upload should be available to jenkins slave only. Several options here:

1. Create special settings.xml just for jenkins slaves. Access for jenkins slave is prohibited for all users except admin, so password will be safe. Everyone will use another settings.xml with creds for download only.
2. Parametrize settings.xml with env variables:

   ```
   <server>
      <id>repo</id>
      <username>${env.REPO_USER}</username>
      <password>${env.REPO_PASSWORD}</password>
    </server>
   ```

On jenkins slaves, REPO_USER/PASSWORD will be set with credentials plugin: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs.
Users will set this vars to download-only creds.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look. I don't really understand how to achieve the first option. A little bit of more context, I'm using Jenkins Shared Pipelines. My dockerfile for Jenkins Slave and Jenkins shared pipelines are all in source control. Basically everything is in source control. So access for Jenkins slave is not allowed but the file will be in source control. Am I missing something?

The second option looks interesting. Will take a look!

Comment: you're right, if dockerfile with settings.xml is in source control, first option won't help

Comment: The 2nd option solved me the problem. Thank you very much!